# iOS app notification badge count not resetting to 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, react-native

We're trying to clear the push-notification badge count when the app *becomes active*, however after successfully clearing, the next notification doesn't give a badge count of 1. Instead, we see what seems to be the total notification count.

So for example we receive 3 notifications - and see the **3** badge, launch the app & hit home again, and the badge has gone. Next time we receive a notification it's not the expected **1**, it's **4**.

This is the code in our `AppDelegate.m`, inside `@implementation AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: How you display badge?

Comment: I think problem is where you are setting the badge number.

Comment: add breakpoint in development build and check whats the badge count in push notification from server. No magic is required on app besides the line you have already added.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah it's something on the server. We're using an API to receive push from a cms, and it seems to be that which sets the count. Currently in talks with the API dev.

Comment: are you try to reset it from server side and check it

Answer (score 2):

in case of foreground in `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` as well:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

in the background reset it in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Where I need to place this in react native app